# How to group by two column for one column in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd like to group the Store Code by the Supplier Code and Branch Code.

Scenarios
[image]

So the result should be like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you combine the store codes with their lines' branch codes, separated by some odd, not likely to be used character, you will the basis for finding and sorting a list of all the existing combinations.

That has an obvious use you'll get to in a moment, but it also has a hidden use:  it will create information for all the rows needed in the output table without having to figure a way to reserve the first four rows for the first supplier because they have four branches but only two rows for the second supplier and exactly six rows for the third supplier and so on. Getting the list of the joined supplier and branch codes, using `UNIQUE` on the pairings to get only one entry for each, and `SORT` to put them in order by supplier then branches will make your table neat and organized logically without external sorting.

Then, each row's entry on that output can be wrapped by formula to pull out the first part for the supplier code column in the output table, and to pull out the part after the separator for the branch column in the output table. Excel has a series of new text handling functions and two of them will be vastly easier than older methods for achieving that although "vastly" is probably a bit exxagerated.

For the third column, the store codes, using `FILTER` on the store code column alone, and basing the second parameter on the string created above matching a similarly created string of the two cells in the output table in the first two columns will yield a list of all the store codes in the store code column matched to their supplier code and branch code pairings. `UNIQUE` will then remove "extras" from each row's list, `SORT` will put them in a logical order, and `TEXTJOIN` will put them together in a concatenated list.

So the three formulas that do this are:

```
=TEXTBEFORE(  SORT(UNIQUE(Supplier&"|"&Branch)),"|")

=TEXTAFTER(  SORT(UNIQUE(Supplier&"|"&Branch)),"|")

=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(Store,  Supplier&"|"&Branch=E2&"|"&F2))))
```

(If your output table has headers in E1:G1 and the data begins in E2:G2 and descends down the rows.)

The first two are `SPILL` formulas, but I am failing at finding a `SPILL` version for the last formula. So it needs copied and pasted down to match the other two columns.

You could combine the first two columns a number of ways into a single formula. This is one:

```
=CHOOSE(  {1,2},  TEXTBEFORE(SORT(UNIQUE(Supplier&"|"&Branch)),"|"),  TEXTAFTER(SORT(UNIQUE(Supplier&"|"&Branch)),"|"))
```

and if a way can be found to make the third a `SPILL` formula, it could be added to that for a single formula in a single cell.